# image still shows translucent opacity after change in opacity value

Tags: html, css, opacity

***functionality:***

The following page is translucent and has an `opacity: 0.68;`and within the page, I have an image with an `opacity: 1.0;`. The main idea is that the the image is placed in an overlay over the translucent background, and the image shouldn't be sharing the same translucent property as the background.

***Issue:***

The image within the translucent page is sharing the same translucent property, even though i have set the opacity property of the image to be 1.0.

How am I able to set the image to be of solid state without showing the opacity property that i have set from the main background?

```css
.BrandMenu {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=98);
  opacity: 0.98;
}
.BrandDescription {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  filter: alpha(opacity=200);
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div id="Park_BrandDescription" class="BrandMenu" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=9; top:0px; margin:auto;">

  <img id="Pa_Description" class="BrandDescription" style="position:absolute; width: 1080px; height:650px; top:500px; background-color: white; left:0px; z-index=99;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is explained in the answer of @eisbehr, but you can have a translucid background with `rgba()` values without affecting the opacity of the children elements:

```css
.BrandMenu {
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.98);
}
.BrandDescription {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="Park_BrandDescription" class="BrandMenu" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: block; top:0px; margin:auto;">

  <img id="Pa_Description" class="BrandDescription" style="position:absolute; width: 1080px; height:650px; top:500px; background-color: white; left:0px;" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
```

And there's no `2.0` value of opacity, the maximum is `1.0`(100%)

Answer (score 3):

You can't make an element fully visible with `opacity`, when the parent elements are not fully visible. The `opacity` is caclulated by the parents, and `1.0` is the maximum. Imaging a setup like this:

```
<div style="opacity: .5;">
  This text here has a opacity of 50%!
  <div style="opacity: .5;">
    This text here has a opacity of 25%!
    <div style="opacity: .5;">
      This text here has a opacity of 12.5%!
      <div style="opacity: 1;">
        This text here has still a opacity of 12.5%!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```